# I am trying to set up DMS for a SQL Server RDS to another SQL Server RDS and when I try to run "exec msdb.dbo.rds_cdc_enable_db"

Tags: sql-server, amazon-rds, aws-dms

I am trying to run the `rds_cdc_enable_db` command and I get

`The EXECUTE permission was denied` on the object `rds_cdc_enable_db`.

Database is `msdb` and schema is `dbo`.  I am using the Master login and password for the source `RDS`.

The SQL Server `RDS` instance is SQL Server Standard.

Answer (score 0):

The `rds_cdc_enable_db` method requires `sysadmin` permissions that you don't have on RDS. What you receive as the *master login* is a custom login that AWS prepared for you and grants you as many permissions as possible without interfering with AWS RDS operations. [See docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.MasterAccounts.html).

According to [RDS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.SQLServer.CommonDBATasks.CDC.html), you should rather use stored procedures provided by AWS in order to enable CDC:

```sql
--Enable CDC for RDS DB Instance
exec msdb.dbo.rds_cdc_enable_db '<database name>'

--Begin tracking a table
exec sys.sp_cdc_enable_table   
   @source_schema           = N'<source_schema>'
,  @source_name             = N'<source_name>'
,  @role_name               = N'<role name>'
```

See also [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.SQLServer.html#CHAP_Source.SQLServer.CDC.RDS.SettingUp) specifically for DMS.